# How to remove the app name on the control pannel on windows mobile?

Tags: windows, mobile

My device is windows mobile 6.5 and I'm trying to remove my installed application.

So I removed all exe/data files what my app used.
But after removing those files, there is still app name in the control pannel's remove Program menu.

How could I remove the app name on the program list?
(I thought it will be removed if I search the app name on the registry and I removed all the registry about "my app" but I failed)

Here's are I removed registry list.

HKLM/Software/Apps/'my app name'
HKLM/Security/AppInstall/'my app name'

Moreover, What should I do to remove the app name?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2008/12/08/uninstalling-applications-programmatically-in-windows-mobile.aspx) what you mean?

Comment: Actually I tried it on my device.
But it didn't work. (it does work on the emulator still.)
So instead of that, I removed the whole programs using remove API and remove registry.